# Yajra Datatable get string by Id

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I had an issue with get string from enum by id.

here's my datatable code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable(
    {
        dom: "lrtip",
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        bSortCellsTop: true,
        ajax: {
            url:  "{{ route('driver.list') }}",
            data: { '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}'},
            type: 'POST',
        },
        columns: [
        { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name', className: 'text-center', 'visible': false,
            'searchable': false, },
        { data: 'gender', name: 'gender', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'race', name: 'race', className: 'text-center', 'visible': false,
            'searchable': false, },
        { data: 'email', name: 'email', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'mobile', name: 'mobile', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'nric', name: 'nric', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'date_of_birth', name: 'date_of_birth', className: 'text-center', 'visible': false,
            'searchable': false, },
        { data: 'license', name: 'license', className: 'text-center', },
        { data: 'type', name: 'type', className: 'text-center', 'visible': false,
            'searchable': false, },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', className: 'text-center', orderable: false, searchable: false  },
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                $('#datatable thead tr#filterRow th:not(:last-child)').each( function () {
                    var title = $('#datatable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                    $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="col-md-12" placeholder="Search by '+title+'" />');
                    if (title == "Gender") {
                        var select = $('<select>');
                        var genderList = {!! json_encode($genderList) !!};
                        for (var i = 0;i < genderList.length; i++) {
                            option = $('<option>',{
                                value: i,
                                text: genderList[i],
                            });
                            select.append(option);
                        }
                        $(this).html(select);
                    }
                });
                $('select').select2({
                    allowClear: true,
                });  
                $("#datatable thead input,#datatable thead select").on('keyup change', function () {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    datatable.column( $(this).parent().index()).search(this.value).draw();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

here's my enum code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Enums;

final class Gender {
const MALE = 0;
const FEMALE = 1;
public static function getList() {
    return [
        Gender::MALE,
        Gender::FEMALE,
    ];
}

public static function getArray() {
    $result = [];
    foreach (self::getList() as $arr) {
        $result[$arr] = self::getString($arr);
    }
    return $result;
}

public static function getString($val) {
    switch ($val) {
        case 0:
            return "Male";
        case 1:
            return "Female";
    }
}

}

?>
```

I want to take the string from enum by id.

why when I choose male/female it didn't process the data ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Yajra's Datatable package why don't you use a transformer instead, it works well with Fractal, see here: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/transformer

Then you can do something like this in your transformer:

```
public function transform(Driver $driver)
{
    return [
        'gender' => $driver->gender == 0 ? 'Male' : 'Female'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I have to add new DriverTransformer model ?

Comment: Yes. Let me know if you're stuck and I can throw up some example code.

Comment: No probs, glad you found the solution!